# F# - Writing a function that accepts both non-generic and generic argument

Tags: f#

I defined await function like this:

```
let await (task : Task<'a>) =
    task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

and two tasks like this:

```
let stringTask = new Task<string>(fun () -> "something")

let unitTask = new Task(fun () -> printf "something")
```

Calling them like this:

```
let stringResult = await stringTask
await unitTask
```

But the second is not generic and I can't call `await` for it, thus I edited the function argument like this:

```
let await (task : Task) =
    task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The problem is now the `await stringTask` is returning `unit` instead of `string`.

How should I write the await function to accept both Task<'a> and Task as the parameter and await it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original definition for `await` is fine.

The problem is with `unitTask` which is not generic. Make it generic the same way you did with `stringTask`:

```
let unitTask = new Task<unit>(fun () -> printf "something")
```

If you want to handle both generic `Task<'a>` and non-generic `Task`, you have 2 options.

Create 2 `await` functions (the functional way):

```
let await     (task : Task<'a>) = task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
let awaitUnit (task : Task    ) = task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

or create 2 `Await` members for instance on type `Task` (the OO way):

```
type Task with 
    static member Await (task : Task    ) = task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
    static member Await (task : Task<'a>) = task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

By convention members use Pascal case so I used `Await` instead of `await`.

Remember to call `task.Start()` before you call your `await`.

Comment: Thanks, but what about in a situation I'm using someone else's API? (The lib api Returning a `Task`)

Comment: I expanded on my answer

Answer (score 5):

`Async.AwaitTask` already has overloads for both `Task<'a>` and `Task`, so unless you really need a helper function, you can use it directly:

```
let stringResult = Async.AwaitTask stringTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
Async.AwaitTask unitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

And if this is your actual code and you really need to block the thread to wait for those results, you can also just use the Task API directly to save the Task -> Async translation overhead:

```
let stringResult = stringTask.Result
unitTask.Wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Task -> Task<unit>` helper function to convert `Task` objects you get from the API into `Task<unit>`.  I suspect that this isn't the best way to do it, since it has been a while since I've paid much attention to the differences between F# async and the framework's Task-based asynchrony, but this works in a trivial extension of your example:

```
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

let toUnitTask (t : Task) =
    new Task<_>(fun () -> t.Start(); t |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously)

let await (task : Task<_>) =
    task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

let stringTask = new Task<string>(fun () -> Thread.Sleep 3000; "something")
let unitTask = new Task(fun () -> Thread.Sleep 2000; printfn "something") |> toUnitTask

stringTask.Start()
unitTask.Start()

let stringResult = await stringTask
await unitTask
```